# Java 1.6.15, Mac OS X, JMenuItem does not disapear

Tags: java, macos, swing, jvm, jmenuitem

My application uses some implementation of licensing mechanics. Depending of license type some menu items must be invisible. And now I've run into problem on Mac OS X 10.6.2. Java version 1.6.0_15. Menu items just won't disapear no matter what. I debugged method which implements that functionality and saw with my own eyes - attribute *visible* becomes false! And there's no code wich could change that in this application. Even more - app works fine on all Windows-es i have with last JRE and on OS X updated to 10.6.8 with Java 1.6.0_31. 
Is this a buggy Apple's JVM? What is the best solution in such case?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: i rely on someone who experienced similar problem before. I don't sure, i could reproduce problem myself. I'll try though.

Comment: *"I'll try though."* +1.  It should not take more than about 40 lines of SSCCE to reproduce.  BTW - why not add actions to the menu items and disable the action?  That will result in the menu item looking 'disabled' rather than 'disappearing' - but than that would most likely be the path of least surprise for the user in any case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: There are some options about which user don't need to know. Foolproof, kind of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried to create SSCCE and failed. In simple subclass of JFrame all works fine. Items disapear as intended. But instead i've found [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/CrossPlatform/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate2LeopardUpdate7RN/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate2LeopardUpdate7RN.pdf). And it says:

> Radar #7420583
>   JMenuItems setVisible(false) do not hide. 
>   Description:
>   The screen menu bar would not hide JMenuItems that were marked setVisible(false). 
>   Resolution: This issue has been resolved.

As I expected it's  Apple's fault.
What's left for me is to explicitly check for runtime version on Mac OS X.
Any other solutions are welcome in comments(except of upgrading java - it's not my area of responsibility).

Comment: But that says it's resolved, which implies that it's no longer Apple's fault.

Comment: @Tharwen: it's true, but i can't be sure potential user has proper version of JVM. I don't want to make explicit version check, but can't afford to leave things like this. Maybe you can propose a workaround?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well... I don't think there's much you can do about that...

Comment: Well, it's to bad. Thank you anyway